# Event listener stops listening

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mouseover, event-listener

I've set up a 16x16 square grid and made the background of each square change color when hovered over.

I then have a button to clear the starting grid and prompt the user for dimensions for a new grid, which then sets up the next grid and seems to work fine.

However, at this stage, the existing Event Listener for the 'mouseover' event no longer works.

I've checked all the syntax and for any variable name clashes and have come unstuck - please help!

My script/html/css is here: https://codepen.io/Turbo124/pen/KKyMzxX

and my script is also shown below - thank you.

```
const gridContainer = document.querySelector('#grid-container');

function makeGrid(rows, cols) {
    gridContainer.style.setProperty('--gridRows', rows);
    gridContainer.style.setProperty('--gridCols', cols);
    for (let i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {
        let newCell = document.createElement("div");
        // newCell.textContent = (i + 1);
        newCell.classList.add("cells");
        gridContainer.appendChild(newCell);
    }
   
}

makeGrid(16,16);

document.querySelectorAll('.cells').forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        console.log("hover");
    })
})

button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", clearGrid);
button.addEventListener("click",setGrid);

function clearGrid() {
    let temp = gridContainer.childElementCount;
    for (let i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
    gridContainer.removeChild(gridContainer.childNodes[0]);
    }
}

function setGrid() {
    let temp = prompt("Enter number of squares per side")
    makeGrid(temp, temp);

};
```

Comment: because you do not bind the events again? The `document.querySelectorAll('.cells').forEach(cell => {` does not magically start running again. Just bind the event when you create the cell. No need to look them up.

Comment: It is quite clear. You delete the old elements and create new ones. The event listener was listening for action on the old ones. Ergo you need to create new listener for the new elements.

Comment: `newCell.addEventList......`

Comment: thank you for explaining, I've moved the event listener into the makeGrid function and it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the mouse over wont work on the dynamically created elements try and place the mouseover on the parent div and check which target element triggered the event.Here have a look at this an article about event delegation https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate.